# Is it possible to slice a column from 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, slice

When I wish to slice a row from a 2-D array in `c` I can do the following:

```
void PrintArray(int *arr, int arr_size);
int main(){
    int arr[4][4] = {
            {10, 13, 56, 66},
            {23, 57, 59, 67},
            {36, 70, 74, 75},
            {40, 75, 80, 91}
    };
    PrintArray(arr[2], 4);
    return 0;
}

void PrintArray(int *arr, int arr_size) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < arr_size; i++) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Which prints:

```
36 70 74 75
```

I was wondering if it's possible to do the same column-wise in some elegant/efficient way.

I could transpose the matrix and do the same but it so cumbersome to do it that way.

### Note:

I suspect that it might not be possible, but I was wondering if there is a more educated answer to whether it's possible or not.

Comment: If you are fine with the array always being 4x4 and can restrict values to +/- 127 then there's various very fast byte tricks you can use.

Comment: @Lundin I guess I don't restrict it, but I would still be happy to find a reference to what you describe, or you could even give it as an answer

Comment: Given your response to the (now deleted) answer, the answer to your question is simply "No". Your code works because C stores arrays by rows.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica I see, so there is no way to overcome this in any way. If I wish to do it I need to transpose the matrix, or just pass the matrix as is and the desired column index and perform the logic. Right?

Comment: @DavidS: Yes, because that's how things are laid out in memory and C doesn't add any syntactic sugar for working with multidimensional arrays. Heck the way "multidimensional" arrays work in C is just by happenstance of implicit pointer-decay. When you have a `int a[10][10];` and do `a[5]` what you actually get is a `int*`, because that's what `a[5]` decays to. If you want elegant syntactic sugar for arrays you need a different language (like FORTRAN, which has supported this kind of access for decades).

Comment: @DavidS Regarding the byte tricks, you could declare a `uint32_t array [4]` then mask out individual bytes with `(array[i] >> 8*j) & 0xFF` etc. That's about as fast as C code can get, but it only works for nx4 matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No elegant or effective way as such exists, because arrays are essentially raw memory, but a matrix is an application-layer concept.

It just so happens that an array of 4 `int[4]` arrays can be accessed by letting array number *n* decay into a pointer to the first element, because that's how items are guaranteed to be laid out in memory (from LS address to MS address, "left to right"). But there is no particularly elegant trick to do the other way around, short of accessing each array item with `arr[i][j]`.

Notably, you could chose to create a matrix either as `mat [row][col]` or `mat[col][row]` on the application layer. The left-most dimension/index of an array of arrays doesn't necessarily have to correspond to the mathematical definition of a matrix in the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you cast your array as (int*), then you can define this function:

```
void PrintCol (int *arr, int col, int row_size, int arr_size) {
    int i;
    for (i = col; i < arr_size; i += row_size) {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And call it like this, assuming you want to print column offset 1.

```
PrintCol((int*)arr, 1, 4, 16);
```

Whose output should look like this:

```
$ gcc slice.c && ./a.out
13 57 70 75
```

One thing you should do is compare the PrintArray `for` loop with the one in `PrintCol`.

The only difference between the assembly generated should be the instruction for how `i` is assigned initially and how `i` is incremented.

In that sense, `PrintArray` is indeed more efficient but not by much. The cost of "transpose matrix plus PrintArray" will always(?) be more than "PrintCol".